# Django Custom Filter Tag Returns Nothing

Tags: django, filter, django-templates, tags, django-filters

I want to filter the objects in a model using custom filter tag, but I got nothing.
Here is the profile_tag.py in the templatetags folder.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
from ..models import Profile
@register.inclusion_tag('register/profile.html')
def filter_profile(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return {'profile' : profile}
```

I loaded the tag in the html file:  {% load profile_tags %}

Then I tried to print {{profile.user}} in different ways, but nothing is showing up.

If I have an error, can you fix it or can you give me another solution to filter the model by the user.

note: I don't want to use the `Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)` in the views.py file.

Thanks.

Comment: What you here try to do is a *context processor*, not a template tag. A template tag would mean that you write `{% filter_profile %}`, but then it would still not work.

Comment: Did you install the context processor in the `settings.py`?

Comment: yes I did, I just want to filter the Profile objects within the template.

Comment: but here `Profile` is a *collection* of `Profile` objects, hence it has *no* `user` attribute.

Comment: That's why I used the filter(user=request.user), so It will return only one object.

Comment: no, `.filter(..)` always returns a `QuerySet`, so a *collection* of object (it can contain zero, one, or more elements). With `.get(..)` you retrieve a single object (or it raises an exception if there is no, or multiple such `Profile` objects).

Comment: I tried it, still I got nothing.

Comment: Do you think it's wise to use (inclusion_tag) to filter objects?